# For what values of k does x^3 + ax^2 + kx + ak (a and k are real) have: (a) one real root (b) 3 real roots

Tags: polynomials

For what values of k does x^3 + ax^2 + kx + ak (a and k are real) have: (a) one real root (b) 3 real roots. I've been trying but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can factor 
$$a k+a x^2+k x+x^3=(x+a) \left(x^2+k\right)$$
and see that one real solution is $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}\land k>0$.

Three real solutions are when $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}\land k<0$

Comment: Thank you!! I feel so stupid now that I didn't try to factorise it in the first place...

Comment: Oh man! Where you been so long? @Raffaele